# How to find my Max point value from my Telerik ChartDataPointCollection

Tags: c#, .net, charts, telerik

i have `ChartView` that received read time data via timer.
my `Chart` contain only 60 points and after 60 points the oldest point deleted so my `Chart` contain only 60 points.

Now i want to know the current biggest point from my `Chart`:

```
AreaSeries series;
Telerik.Charting.DataPoint num = chartDataPointCollection.Max<Telerik.Charting.DataPoint>();
```

The problem is that at this point error occurs:

```
At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

And i don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Telerik.Charting.DataPoint` doesn't implement `IComparable` - that is, the data point doesn't know how to compare itself to another data point (do you want to compare x values? y values?). You could loop through all data points, and keep track of the max value (x or y) and the corresponding datapoint:

```
DataPoint maxPoint = null;
double maxValue = double.MinValue;
foreach (DataPoint point in chartDataPointCollection)
{
    if (point.X > maxValue)
    {
        maxValue = point.X; // or point.Y, or whatever criteria you want to use.
        maxPoint = point;
    }
}
if (maxPoint != null)
{
    // do stuff with the max point
}
```